# TensorFlow Keras Error: expected flatten_input to have shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am using TensorFlow Keras to create a machine learning model for a set of data.  I have been able to get the model to compile, however when I try to run a prediction, I get the following error:

```
    prediction = model.predict(test)
  File "C:\Users\mbaker\PycharmProjects\UnileverPatentWatch\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1864, in predict
    x, check_steps=True, steps_name='steps', steps=steps)
  File "C:\Users\mbaker\PycharmProjects\UnileverPatentWatch\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 992, in _standardize_user_data
    class_weight, batch_size)
  File "C:\Users\mbaker\PycharmProjects\UnileverPatentWatch\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1117, in _standardize_weights
    exception_prefix='input')
  File "C:\Users\mbaker\PycharmProjects\UnileverPatentWatch\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_utils.py", line 332, in standardize_input_data
    ' but got array with shape ' + str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected flatten_input to have shape (1872,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

My ML code is:

```
    train_features = np.array(train_features)
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(len(train_features[0]),)),
    keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(7, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])

model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(),
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_features, train_labels, epochs=10)

    x = 0
for test in test_features:
    test = np.array(test)
    print(test)
    print(len(test))
    prediction = model.predict(test)
    print(test_patents[x], prediction, labelIndex[prediction])
    x += 1
```

test_features is a list of feature sets for which I want a prediction.  I have tried alternately passing the feature set as a numpy array as seen above or as a list and both methods have resulted in the above error.  The data is being passed to the predict function in the same format as was provided to train the model.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please print test.shape

Comment: print(test.shape) yielded: (1870,)

Comment: test_features[-1].shape? it doesn't run any piece of loop?

Comment: Reshape your test to be (1,1870)

Comment: test_features[-1].shape yielded: (1871,).  It is also worth noting that there seems to be some variability in the number ranging from 1870-1873, however when the shape of the input data changes, so too does the number in the error message.  I believe it may be some form of rounding error, however my training data is created using the same process.

Comment: Reshaping the array appears to have worked, thanks.